# implementing a map container with getter for iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, getter

I'm trying to access value and key using *iterator as shown :

```
for (Map<K, V>::iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it) {
V& value = (*it).getValue(); // or*it.getValue();
}
```

it does not work,even the drop menu does not show anything (working with eclipse) .
the only way to get it working is to do the following :

```
Node<K, V>& node = *it;
V& value = node.getValue();
```

I have both const and none const getters,also the* operator return reference to the node.

**edit:**
i'm implementing my own map code.

**edit 2**
I figured it out, my * operator was returning a pointer and i was thinking it returns & .
thank you all

Comment: What error do you get? BTW are K and V template parameters?

Comment: It looks like you're not using `std::map` but some other container. You'll need to post some code to show what the container iterator looks like.

Comment: What is `Map`? Is it an alias for `std::map`, or something non-standard?

Comment: i didn't run the code with (*it).getValue(); , and yes they're  template parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the map type is `std::map`, or something similar that conforms to the standard Associative Container interface, then it contains key-value pairs, of type `std::pair<const K, V>`, and that is what you get when you dereference the iterator.

To access the value, you need the second element of the pair:

```
V & value = it->second;
```

If the map type doesn't conform to the standard interface, then you'll need to look at its documentation; I can't guess how it might work.

Comment: @Emad4U: In that case, it would be a good idea to post the exact error message, and (minimal) definitions of `iterator` and `Node` showing the declarations of `operator*` and `getValue`. It's impossible to guess what might be wrong with your own code if we can't see it.